# python nltk download from external url

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

A server I am running nltk tests from does not have direct access to the external nltk models at `http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/` but we do have a private mirror setup to access the nltk models.

How can I tell the ntlk downloader to install from the private mirror as opposed to http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/?

I was expecting this to work but does not:

```
>>> nltk.downloader.Downloader(server_index_url='https://MyNltkMirror/index.xml').download()
NLTK Downloader
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloader> d

Download which package (l=list; x=cancel)?
  Identifier> abc
    Downloading package abc to /path/to/nltk_data...
    Error downloading 'abc' from
        <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-
        pages/packages/corpora/abc.zip>:   <urlopen error [Errno 104]
        Connection reset by peer>
```

Or is it possible that I am doing this right and there is an access issue connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com from my server?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you downloading the data from? Most probably you're behind a proxy or getting blocked. Check with your network administrator?

Comment: The firewall plumbing is in place between the nltk mirror and `https://raw.githubusercontent.com`.  It would however be an issue if the nltk downloader is trying to download directly from github as opposed to the mirror.  This is why i was hoping for confirmation that I have this syntactically correct, or if there is another downloader option to do what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: Is there a particular package that you would like to download?

Comment: Yes, would like to download all of them

Comment: Let me try and see whether our alternative content host can be out-facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the package(s) without using the interactive mode.

```
# Your mirror.
mirror_url = "http://example.com/my_corpus_data/index.xml"
dler = nltk.downloader.Downloader(mirror_url)

# Directly download the package(s) without using the interactive mode.
dler.download('popular')
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks.  Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error message as listed in the original post.